# TypeScript Cannot find namespace despite Variable being in same Class

Tags: node.js, typescript, callback

I'm trying to define Callbackdefinitions to make it easier to work with many callbacks in my Node.js project.

My database.ts file looks like that:

```
export default class Database {

    //Export the enums
    public static LoadObjectResponse = LoadObjectResponse;

    //Export Callback definitions
    public static loadObjectCallback: (resultCode: Database.LoadObjectResponse) => void;//ERROR
    ...
}

enum LoadObjectResponse {
    ERROR_ON_LOADING, //"Error on Loading Object.",
    OBJECT_NOT_FOUND //"Object not found."
}
```

So I want a loadObjectCallback defined, that says that the parameter has to be of the enum Type LoadObjectResponse. But when I try to do it like that, the compiler always gives the error

```
Cannot find namespace "Database"
```

I don't understand why it gives me the error, the variable itself is in the definition of Database, why doesn't it work?

It gives me the same error when I try to use it in Classfunction definitions:

```
public static loadObject(MongoModel, searchObject, callback: Database.LoadObjectResponse) {//ERROR namespace Database not found
```

Again Error:

```
Cannot find namespace "Database"
```

Inside of functions in the Database class calling

```
Database.LoadObjectResponse
```

works flawlessly, why doesn't it work in variable definitions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Cannot find namespace "Database"

This is a common learning curve issue. You need to understand and be comfortable with the **intutive** concept of *declaration spaces* : https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/project/declarationspaces

Things are distinct in the *type* declaration space or in the *variable* declaration space.

In your case `public static LoadObjectResponse` is a *variable* hence cannot be used as a *type* (error on annotation usage `: Database.LoadObjectResponse`).

## Fix

Please don't treat a `class` as a `namespace`. The *file is a module*.

```
export class Database {
    //Export Callback definitions
    public static loadObjectCallback: (resultCode: LoadObjectResponse) => void;//ERROR
}

export enum LoadObjectResponse {
    ERROR_ON_LOADING, //"Error on Loading Object.",
    OBJECT_NOT_FOUND //"Object not found."
}
```

Also beware of `export default` : https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/defaultisbad

Comment: I believe that almost every question on this site `is a common learning curve issue`. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's because `Database.LoadObjectResponse` is a property and not a type. You can't use properties as types.

To make this work, change it to use the type of the property:

```
static loadObjectCallback: (resultCode: typeof Database.LoadObjectResponse) => void;
```

Or refer directly to the enum type of `LoadObjectResponse`:

```
static loadObjectCallback: (resultCode: LoadObjectResponse) => void
```